# I want to create src_ token for card information - stripe

Tags: php, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I am developing one mobile app with flutter and stripe,

It is existing app so we need to use it's payment method same as old version has so in old version of app when user enter card they are generating card token starting with **'src_'** but I have check **flutter_stripe** library and not found any option to do that I also check **Stripe's php library** but can't find anything there.

As per my research I think stripe is not proving feature to generate token with **'src_'** formate from now, **Is there any solution or replacement for that?**

Thank!

Comment: Using Sources (`src_xxx`) to accept payments with Stripe is no loner recommended and not supported by the flutter_stripe library. Instead you should change you app to work with PaymentIntent (`pi_xxx`) which works in Flutter. You can learn more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements).